# how to access action result returning value asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

i have method in home controller like this.

```
 public actionResult page1()
 {
     //some operation here
     return view(someValue);
  }
```

can anybody tell What it is exactly doing and how to access "someValue" in view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`someValue` will be the `Model` in the view.  In order for this to work, the view for `page1` needs to be bound to that model type.  So, let's assume that `someValue` is of type `MyModel`.  Then the `page1` view would begin with an `@model` declaration such as:

```
@model MyWebApplication.MyNamespace.MyModel
```

Basically the first line in the view would be this fully-qualified type name, telling the view what type of model will be used.  Then anywhere else in the view you can reference the instance of the model (which is `someValue` in this case) by referencing `Model`.  So you might emit a section heading based on a model property, for example:

```
<h1>@Model.Title</h1>
```

(Note that the type of the model can't be a string, since `View(string)` is already an overload for the `View()` method.  If you need just a string, wrap it in a custom object.)

Comment: can i return bitmap.drawing.Image type object within return view(ImageObj)?

Comment: @user2408194: You can technically use any object you want.  I guess the question with `Image` is what you plan on doing with it in the view.  If you're trying to display an image, you're probably not going about it the right way.

Comment: i want to give image to webservice that can take HttpPostedFileBase file.i called my webserivce from from another actionResult method

Comment: @user2408194: That sounds... convoluted.  And also well outside the scope of the question asked.  If you're trying to store an entire image in the view to be posted to another action, that's *probably* not the way to go.  Once the image is already server-side, it's best to persist it somewhere server-side.  It's really hard to be more specific without knowing what you're trying to do, though.  Maybe you can update the question with an example?